# Clion not recognizing Toolset mingw64

Tags: java, clang, clion

Here is my configuration for Clion

[image]

Here is what is in the C:\msys64 directory

[image]

Here is what is included in the C:\msys64\mingw64 directory
[image]

All these packages are installed by MSYS

Comment: Can you try with a `MinGW` toolchain instead of `MinGW_Clang` or did you install the [packages necessary for clang with MinGW](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#setup-clang)?

Comment: I have all the packages installed and tried regular MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the issue CPP-28457 on JetBrains YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-28457), it seems that an update of MinGW headers broke CLion's ability to detect MSYS2's MinGW.

[An reply](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-28457#focus=Comments-27-5827827.0-0) provides **a temporary fix** by making an soft link.

You can try making a symbol link with an elevated PowerShell under the instructions by, for example, [Create Symbolic Link with PowerShell](https://winaero.com/create-symbolic-link-windows-10-powershell/):

- Open an elevated PowerShell
- Change directory to `<MSYS2_INSTALL_DIR>/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32`
- Making a link by typing: `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path ./include -Target ../include`